# .htaccess rewrite rules for category and product

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, seo, oscommerce

i have a oscommerce site, i wan to use seo freindly urls, I got a tutorial from [here](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/oscommerce/oscommerce_sef_url.htm)

I basically wanted to change the ID number present in a URL to a URl that will contain name of product or category in it. an example of such url is

`http://katanamotorsports.com/innovative-mounts-steel-mounts-prelude-replacement-mount-p-1075.html`

i want to modify .htaccess file so that these seo friendly url are actually redirected to respective page with respect to category and product.

i am new bee in learning, and i am totally a new bee in .htaccess

can anybody help me?

Comment: What does your current URLs look like?

Comment: i have qouted the url right above

Comment: Yes this is the URL a user will see. But what is your 'real' URL? Something like http://katanamotorsports.com/product.php?id=12314 maybe?

Comment: you correctly got my point, the basic structure of url was just like you pasted, but after i changed the options in admin panel, the new URl became as i pasted above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a RewriteRule in your .htaccess to map the external URL (as visible by a user) to your internal version.

What you want to do is activate the RewriteEngine, then write a RewriteRule that will drop the first part of the URI.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^[a-z0-9\-]+-p-([0-9]+)\.html$ /product.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^[a-z0-9\-]+-c-([0-9]+)\.html$ /category.php?id=$1
```

Comment: thanks for this, one clarity, will redirect each page to it resptive php page?

Comment: Yes this will rewrite any url starting with (letters/numbers/dash as separator) and ending with a numerical id to some php page. The $1 allows you to write the found ID at the right spot.

Comment: can you explain the mapping here? what i want to know is, how this redirect will take effect? wether a database will be searched for it? how exact produect id will be determined? by matching the name in some where in the files or database?

Comment: If someones goes to this url http://katanamotorsports.com/innovative-mounts-steel-mounts-prelude-replacement-mount-p-1075.html he won't see any redirection. But on your server the request will be sent to product.php?id=xxx and you'll be able to normally see it in your script. Then you can query your database from your PHP (or other language) script.

Comment: if you see the structure of external URL, you will see '-p-' in it, denoting product, and in some url it will be '-c-' , denoting category, what i think of seeing the answer that, it will redirect all the pages to product.php, Am I correct? please update the answer to address this issue

Comment: what if my orginal URL is http://katanamotorsports.com/product_info.php?products_id=1075 ?

Comment: should it be /product_info.php?products_id=$1?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use "SEO Friendly" urls like this.  They are NOT currently SEO friendly.  Search engines liked them 10 years ago.  In the last five years they really only hurt.

- Google gives almost no weight to keywords in the url
- Google gives weight to sites that it determines satisfy users

So, don't design urls for search engines, design them for users.  Users like

- Urls that are short (maybe they can type them or remember them)
- Urls that are meaningful (They can see what they are about before clicking on them)
- Urls that don't contain repetition or numbers like ids

It would be far better for you to have your url be:

```
http://katanamotorsports.com/prelude-replacement-mount
```

Comment: Why didn't you provide a solution to your comment?

Comment: I'm suggesting that they take a step back.  Maybe their problem isn't what they think it is.  iMat provided the practically applicable rewrite rules before I answered.

Comment: Ok, understand. Your answers aren't exactly the same solution, therefore I asked.